# In Databricks, check whether a path exist or not

Tags: csv, exception, path, load, databricks

I am reading CSV files from datalake store, for that I am having multiple paths but if any one path does not exist it gives exception. I want to avoid this expection.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @HaukeMallow Thanks for replying, I have shared my code below, I am facing issues, I call a function sqlContext.read.format('csv').load(<string with comma seperated paths>). If any one of the does not exist, then i get 'u path does not exist' exception, And I dont want to get this exception. I have shared my code below. Any help or any alternative will be highly appreciated.

Comment: had the same issue and ended up using a try and except block in python, strange that wrapping it in an if statement doesn't equate to false if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Datanovice, you can use hadoop library for that. There is a function in hadoop, which takes a path and tells weather it exists or not, you can start a question in a seperate thread, so that more people can get solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want to check for multiple pathes, the check will fail if one path does not exist. Perhaps you could try a different approach.

For the given example if you want to subselect subfolders you could try the following instead.

Read sub-directories of a given directory:

```
# list all subfolders and files in directory demo
dir = dbutils.fs.ls ("/mnt/adls2/demo")
```

Filter out the relevant sub-directories:

```
pathes = ''

for i in range (0, len(dir)):
  subpath = dir[i].path
  if '/corr' in subpath or '/deci' in subpath and subpath.startswith ('dbfs:/'): # select dirs to read 
    pathes =  pathes + (dir[i].path) + ' '  

# convert the string to a list 
pathes = list(pathes.split())
```

Use the result-list to read the dataframe:

```
df = (spark.read
  .json(pathes))
```

Comment: path = '/data/logs/2018.10.01/{*}.csv,/data/logs/2018.10.02/{*}.csv'
// path contains two paths comma seperated.
records = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true').load(paths.split(','), schema = customSchema)
// If both paths exist i dont get error but if any one path does not exist i get exception.

Comment: Right I got your point, that we can check its existance from mount point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

where `path` is a specific variable, you can use to check if it exists (scala):

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt").map(_.name).contains(s"$path/")
```

Comment: Hi kenniey, this will not work if I have glob paths like have wild characters: *

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by running the snippet below, which uses the new [databricks python SDK](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/):

Install the package:
`pip install databricks-sdk`

Python snippet:

```py
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient

# Remember to change the arguments below
w_client = WorkspaceClient(host="my_host", token="my_db_tokens")

# add an absolute path
dbfs_path_exist = w_client.dbfs.exists('/dbfs_my_path')
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

you must Use block blobs for a Mount point to work from databricks and be able to see the blobs in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).